# I am trying to plot every mesh point of a model elephant so that the surface of the elephant wraps around the interior surface of the mirror

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I'm trying to find a way to turn the elephant inside out in a way. Imagine cutting an elephant in half from tail to trunk, stopping right before the trunk. You could flatten the elephant out and wrap it with the elephant's surface now being on the inside. I wonder if you can do this by reflecting the mesh points of the elephant circularly using shelled ellipse. Any suggestions and help are appreciated.

To clarify this is like reflecting each mesh point across the elliptical mirror but in an elliptical manner and not across a simple line or plane. So all the mesh points inside the mirror would now be outside.
Here is the link to all the files.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qB0PiJ6CA98JtgUw9DtszJVqLW_54saU?usp=sharing

```
CylindricalShell = 
 ImplicitRegion[
  700 <= 128.026 x^2 + 93.42 z^2 <= 950 && -3 <= y <= 3, {x, y, z}]
mirror = Translate[
  Region[CylindricalShell, Axes -> True, FaceGrids -> All], {-0.4, 
   0, -0.1}]



elephant = 
  Import["C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\elefante.obj", 
   "GraphicsComplex"];
grid = Graphics3D[elephant, Axes -> True, FaceGrids -> All]
elephantmeshpoints = MeshRegion[elephant]
(*Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[elephantmeshpoints,]*)
vector = Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1.5, 0, 0}}], Axes -> True, 
    FaceGrids -> All}];
(*Working On the Part where: the elephant is turned "inside out" and \
the surface of the elephant is curved around the interior surface of \
the mirror*)

elephantinmirror =  Show[mirror, grid]
SetSystemOptions[
  "LibraryLinkOptions" -> "TestFloatingPointExceptions" -> False];
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/251330/edit) your question, and add the code you’re tried. Posting the code instead of an image makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Please provide the obj file.